# android: Implementation of OSGI framework in android

Tags: android

Can any one help me to give some hint about

How can i implement OSGI framewok i.e. Remotely installation of application,transfer of media, etc in android.

I have some idea on OSGI framework, I want to make application that should be able to install some media dynamically from remote location...

Any idea will be appreciated...THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to try/use Apache Felix as your OSGi container on Android. There are several examples for this available via Google (e.g. [this example](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html)). If you also use Felix' [Bundle Repository](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html), you should be able to load bundles remotely at runtime (if they are also dexed of course).

EDIT: I just saw that this is way old (however, still unanswered).